# No, it's someone else / it's another one

Tags: idiomatic-language

A - One of my clients has decided to drop out.

B - Was that the man you told me about?

A - No, **it's someone else** / **it's another one.**

What would be idiomatic here?

Comment: Syntactically, both are fine. Idiomatically, ***someone else*** is more likely in most contexts. Note that if for some reason a native speaker *didn't* want to use the more common phrasing here, imho he'd more likely say *...it **was** a **different man*** rather than *...[it **is**] **another one***.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic answer, as mentioned by @FumbleFingers, is "someone else." This is largely because the phrase "another one" is commonly used to refer to objects, so referring to humans with the same phrase would feel rather odd. See examples:

> Is that the dress you wanted for Christmas?
>
> No, this is another one.

As opposed to:

> Is that the man you met on Christmas?
>
> No, this is someone else.